# Converting Bitmap into java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Tags: java, ikvm

I'm using IKVM Libraries in my C# project. I can define a BufferedImage using these libraries, Also I can use a Bitmap as BufferedImage source, but there is a problem;

```
 java.awt.image.BufferedImage fileZ =new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(new Bitmap(file));
```

Here is the Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in IKVM.OpenJDK.SwingAWT.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'java.awt.image.ColorModel' threw an exception.
```

file is a string refers to a bitmap file.
and I have added these references to my project:

```
IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
IKVM.OpenJDK.SwingAWT
IKVM.OpenJDK.Util
IKVM.Runtime
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Clarification needed: can you upload the bitmap image so we can take a look at it? Right now it looks like the error is in the bitmap or that you must supply additional information when trying to read it.

Comment: It is not only a static image, just different images with different types from every folder you think.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. And include the error you are getting from it, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not have sufficient information to answer. However, [this post](http://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/mailman/message/6713714/) is related to related to your task. Of particular interest is this line:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

The last parameter specifies image type.

Also other constructors in the [BufferedImage class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) deals with color models. Check them out.

Comment: I tried to add every IKVM DLL as reference but still I have the error, even If I try to create BufferedImage by your code :(